# Power BI rankx with earlier function

Tags: powerbi-desktop, business-objects, powerbi-datasource

My organization is trying to convert SAP BO to Power BI report. In that one of the calculation I can't convert in Power BI DAX.
SAP BO Formula :

```
=If(Rank([Count Of Gender];Top) = Previous(Rank([Count Of Gender];Top))) 
 Then Rank([Count Of Gender];Top)+1 
 Else Rank([Count Of Gender];Top)
```

How to convert this formula into Power BI?

Please guide me. How to solve this issue?

Thanks
Sairam

Comment: Can you please explain this measure in general terms?